# Does the backend's readinessProbe path need to be declared in the Endpoint openapi.yaml file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-networking

I'm deploying a project that is a GKE container backend, with a Cloud Endpoints API on the the front end. It goes through an Ingress and NodePort service. I've declared a readiness probe on the ESP container:

```
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /ping
            port: 8080
```

But I observed that the /ping path must be declared in the openapi.yaml without any security, or else it returns 404, or 401 if declared with some security definition.

Is that expected? I don't see anything about that in the Endpoints Samples repo:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-samples/tree/master/k8s

Answer (score 0):

After more closely examining the documentation and code samples, I discovered that the ESP has a `healthz` argument for that:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: esp
        image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
        args: [
          "-p", "8080",
          "-a", "127.0.0.1:8081",
          "-s", "SERVICE_NAME",
          "--rollout_strategy", "managed",
          "-z", "healthz",
        ]
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-samples/blob/master/k8s/esp_echo_gke_ingress.yaml)

When specifying the healthz argument for the ESP, it configures nginx to just return 200 for that path:

```
% if healthz:
    location = /${healthz} {
      return 200;
      access_log off;
    }
% endif
```

(https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/blob/5c9f586b14db58607d1780966cceac923809c150/start_esp/nginx-auto.conf.template#L123-L128)

So it looks like Google wants you to just do a health check on the ESP container, not your backend.

This answers my original question, although it still does lead to a second question, which is:  Why not health check the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the term "backend" is referred to the nodes of the cluster or the Pods running by GKE. For both cases, GKE is self managed and the healthy of the nodes and the pods is monitored by the Master Node so that they should be always available. More information on this regard can be found in [Kubernetes Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#nodes) and [GKE Cluster Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/).

In this context, the healthchecks used for the GKE ingress doesn't check the backend but the services running in the cluster. To check that these services are OK, readiness and liveness probes are used as explained in this [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/).

Comment: "backend" is the term Cloud Endpoints documentation uses to refer to the container that serves the backend of the api. The ESP container is its sidecar. My concern about having the readinessProbe only check for the health of the ESP container is that if the backend container is not healthy, then the ESP container will continue to try to send requests to it and not immediately fail.

Comment: The API backend in GKE relies on an [Endpoint service](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/choose-endpoints-option#about_the_computing_option_limitations) which is [Service Infrastructure](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/overview). These are services managed by Google and the user should not care about its healthy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to health check your backend,  you need to list the health check path in openapi config for ESP to forward it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but it seems possible to have a healthcheck on the GCE sidecar AND the eventual backend (e.g. the api you have actually built).

The trick is, the healthcheck for your api has to be configured as a readinessprobe on the cloud endpoints container (not your api container). The endpoint that you check also has to have no security against it, so it is publicly accessible (although it seems like you could also configure the health check with an api key).

I followed previous suggestions and also added the "healthz" argument to the esp container. My API is running on port 80 with a unprotected status endpoint at `/api/status`

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: esp
    image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
    args: [
      "--http_port=8081",
      "--backend=127.0.0.1:80",
      "--service=MY SERVICE",
      "--rollout_strategy=managed",
      "-z", "healthz",
    ]
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8081
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /api/status/
        port: 8081
  - name: api
    image: MY IMAGE
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

This worked, so that check is now verifying both containers are running with one `readinessProbe`. Interestingly, when I checked the LoadBalancer, it had also configured one against `/healthz`, when it hadn't been before. That would nbe useful in diagnosing cases where the endpoints container was working, but that api is not